# Haskell type arithmetic: how to access type-level list of lists

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, type-level-computation

I am working on a type-level representation for cell-based database models that features queries as Haskell-types. I got stuck when trying to extract values from a more complex query type.

Let me first show you code that works:

```
-- a model with datapoints defined by a list of "aspects"
-- every aspect has a "dimension" and a list of dimensional values
type Model = Double  $|$ Aspect "currency" '["eur", "usd"]
                      |$ Aspect "flowtype" '["stock", "flow"]
                      |$ Nil

-- extract the aspects from the query type
class GetAspectsSingle a where
  getAspectsSingle :: Proxy a -> [(Dimension, DimValue)]

instance (KnownSymbol d, KnownSymbol v, GetAspectsSingle as)
      => GetAspectsSingle (Aspect d v |$ as) where
  getAspectsSingle _ = (symbolText (Proxy :: Proxy d),
                        symbolText (Proxy :: Proxy v))
                         : (getAspectsSingle (Proxy :: Proxy as))

instance GetAspectsSingle Nil where
  getAspectsSingle _ = []

-- a dummy for the execution of a type-safe query
-- where CellTypeSingle is a type function that evaluates to the expected type
save :: (MonadIO m, GetAspectsSingle q)
      => Proxy model -> Proxy q -> CellTypeSingle model q -> m ()
-- just print aspects instead of actual query
save Proxy query _ = liftIO . print $ getAspectsSingle query

-- an example query
query :: Proxy (Aspect "currency" "eur" |$ Aspect "flowtype" "stock" |$ Nil)
query = Proxy

test :: IO ()
test = save (Proxy :: Proxy Model) query 3.3
```

The key idea is that the type function `CellTypeSingle` evaluates to `Double` and thus the above code compiles, only if `3.3` is of type `Double`.

I want to have queries that allow the selection of several values (of same type) like this:

```
query :: Proxy (Aspect "currency" '["eur", "usd"] |$ Aspect "flowtype" '["stock"] |$ Nil)
query = Proxy
```

I managed to implement the corresponding type function `CellTypeList` that evaluates to `[Double]` in the above case. In order to get the aspects, however, I have to "explode" the query first. I.e. the above query becomes a list of queries.
This is what I tried.

```
saveList :: (MonadIO m, GetAspectsList q)
         => Proxy model -> Proxy q -> CellTypeList model q -> m ()
-- just print aspects instead of actual query
save Proxy query _ = liftIO . print $ getAspectsList query

class GetAspectsList query where
  type GetAspectsListType (query :: Type) :: Type
  getAspectsList :: Proxy query -> GetAspectsListType query -> [[(Dimension, DimValue)]]

instance (GetAspectsList as)
      => GetAspectsList (a |$ as) where
  type GetAspectsListType (a |$ as) = GetAspectsListType (ExplodeQuery (a |$ as))
  getAspectsList = ???
```

Now I got stuck: `ExplodeQuery` evaluates to `'[ '[ Aspect "currency" "eur", Aspect "flowtype" "stock" ], '[ Aspect "currency" "usd", Aspect "flowtype" "stock"] ]`, that is a list of lists on type-level.

I don't know how to extract the *dimension* and *dimensional values* from there.

Comment: What's this `|$` type?

Comment: It's a type operator defined as `data (|$) a b`, uninhabited.

Comment: Please add some additional explanation as to what functionality you'd like to have. What does your query do, list some expected input-output mappings for your functions, etc.

Comment: Please also include the definitions of all mentioned names.

Comment: Also, in `Model` you have `[(Dimension, [DimValue])]`, while `getAspectLists` returns `[[(Dimension, DimValue)]]`. Is that intended?

Comment: I'll upload the whole project to a public github shortly. Hopefully that will help clear things up.

Comment: Check it out: https://github.com/rubenmoor/cellstore

Comment: If you are interested, we might want to chat somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution, thanks to Kosmikus.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, DataKinds, PolyKinds, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeInType #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-unticked-promoted-constructors #-}

module IsList where

import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeLits hiding (Nat)
import GHC.Types (Type)

type family Extract (k :: Type) :: Type where
  Extract Symbol = String
  Extract [a]    = [Extract a]

class Extractable (a :: k) where
  extract :: Proxy (a :: k) -> Extract k

instance KnownSymbol a => Extractable (a :: Symbol) where
  extract p = symbolVal p

instance Extractable ('[] :: [a]) where
  extract _ = []

instance (Extractable x, Extractable xs) => Extractable (x ': xs) where
  extract _ = extract (Proxy :: Proxy x) : extract (Proxy :: Proxy xs)
```

It's not even that complicated, but I didn't get the nesting straight. This solutions works for lists of lists nested to arbitrary depths.

The `type family` should probably be an associated type family of the `Extractable` class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but I'll say this. Types are primarily useful for classifying values. Building up a lot of type-level information, erasing it at the value-level using a `Proxy`, and then trying to recover it using classes to pattern-match on types results in complicated code (as you've seen) and doesn't really buy you anything in terms of safety or terseness.

Keep it simple. My advice is to think more carefully about what information your API clients will know in advance - this is type-level stuff - and what clients will want to construct dynamically. Use the type-level stuff to classify the value-level stuff.

In this instance, your users will know their *schema* in advance - the various dimensions of the model - but they generally won't know which views over those dimensions they'll be querying.

---

Here's a sketch, which won't necessarily help you out directly, but should at least point you in the right direction. Pay attention to how I use types to classify values, not just as meaningless bits of compile-time data. This allows me to use the class system to generate code in a type-directed fashion, leading to a concise API without sacrificing safety. Plus, if you're willing to forego `TypeOperators` and `PatternSynonyms`, this solution is entirely Haskell 98.

This is what the API for the library looks like:

```
data Currency = EUR | USD deriving Show
data FlowType = Stock | FlowType deriving Show

-- this class just wraps up knowledge of the type's name.
-- You could generate these instances using Template Haskell
instance Aspect Currency where
    aspectName = const "Currency"
instance Aspect FlowType where
    aspectName = const "FlowType"

-- queries contain a currency and a flowtype
type Model = () :&: Currency :&: FlowType

myQuery :: Q Model
myQuery = () :&: EUR :&: Stock :@ 3.3
```

The user defines their own aspect types like `Currency` and `FlowType`, and writes instances of `Aspect` for each of them. They then compose the aspects into a bigger type using `:&:`, terminating the list using `I`. Then, when the time comes to build a query, the client has to provide values for the various aspects in the correct order.

Here's how it's implemented. Models that are built using the `:&:` type combinator will automatically be instances of the following `Query` class.

```
class Query a where
    showQuery :: a -> String
```

I'm representing models built with `:&:` as nested tuples. This allows me to build and recurse on tuples of arbitrary size. `Q` simply pairs up a `Model` with a `Double` value, and `A` is just a marker newtype for aspects.

```
infixl 5 :&:
type (m :&: a) = (m, A a)
pattern m :&: a = (m, A a)

newtype A a = A a

infixl 3 :@
data Q m = m :@ Double
```

Instances of `Query` compile a query into a string by structural recursion on the nested tuple. (If we'd used flat tuples, we'd have to write [lots of instances](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Show.html#line-223) of `Query` - one for each size of tuple - though it would improve performance somewhat because unpacking a tuple is always O(1).)

```
instance Query a => Query (Q a) where
    showQuery (a :@ x) = showQuery a ++ "@" ++ show x
instance (Query a, Query b) => Query (a, b) where
    showQuery (x, y) = showQuery x ++ ", " ++ showQuery y
instance Query () where
    showQuery = const ""
instance Aspect a => Query (A a) where
    showQuery (A x) = aspectName (proxy x) ++ ": " ++ show x
        where proxy :: a -> Proxy a
              proxy = const Proxy
```

The `Aspect` class just wraps up static knowledge of the type's name so that we can use it in the compiled string.

```
class Show c => Aspect c where
    aspectName :: Proxy c -> String
```

The proof of the pudding is in the eating:

```
ghci> showQuery myQuery
", Currency: EUR, FlowType: Stock@3.3"  -- the leading comma is fixable. You get the idea
```

Comment: I started off with an approach based on type-classes. It's in the github repo that I linked in a comment under the question. I have to compare your code with my initial type-class approach ... I'm afraid, a type-class approach does not result in a concise, type-safe interface for queries.

Comment: @ruben.moor Huh? I just gave you an example of a concise type-safe interface based on classes.

Comment: Ok, maybe you need to help me there. My requirement for a type-safe query is: The model defines, given a number of aspects, what (Haskell-) datatype there is. When writing a query later, the compiler knows the type of the query result and can typecheck. That way I extend type-safety into the database. From what I understand, that is not possible w/o use of type families (which makes my code so complicated). In terms of conciseness: the aspect type-class and instances add quite some boilerplate. Btw I put a link to the complete code in github.

Comment: If you want to establish a link between the query type and the result type then type families (or their cousins, functional dependencies) are the way to go. It needn't be complicated though, it's actually a relatively minor adjustment to the code I presented.